# Conditional GET Request and Expiry Header testing with Firebug-NET

Tags: performance, firebug

I'm using `Firebug's NET` feature to measure the performance of our application. I'm a bit confused the way it is displaying the timeline. We have enabled `Expiry header` for all static files(it is 30 days from the current date). Now even if the resource is available in cache, it still makes a conditional GET (that is what I think). Ideally there shouldn't make a connection to the server, but it takes 93ms to create a connection. Please find the image that I've attached.
Can some one please help me to understand this better?[image: Response TimeLine of Firebug]

Answer (score 1):

The HTTP response contains a header entry "Etag". ETag is a cache validator tag.

The HTTP Client on seeing this response will always verify with the server if the Content has been updated.

Cache Validator tag has higher preference over other Cache control tags.

If you want content to be served from cache without it being validate on the server side then only keep the Expires header and remove the ETag header.